# Angular 1.x, Inject dependency in config

Tags: angularjs

Been struggling the last hours with trying to get access to dependencies in my router config, looked at providers but can't seem to understand how they would help me. Long story short: I have a module named 'ngOpenFB' and i need to be able to access said module in the config of my router module.

I need to access the 'ngOpenFB' module to use it in a state.resolve, checking if the user is logged in before allowing a reroute basically.

Below is how i wish i would be able to access ngFB, and of course i know i can't, but what are possible solutions and best practices?

**EDIT**: I know i can use a listener to check for $stateChangeStart and hijack the route change event, for many reasons that would be my last resort.

```
angular.module('app.routes', ['ngOpenFB'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, ngFB) {

    var loginRequired = function ($q, $location) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve();

        // HERE I NEED TO ACCESS THE MODULE
        if (ngFB.getLoginStatus().$$state.value.status !== 'connected') {
             $location.path('/nologin');
        }

        return deferred.promise;
    };


    $stateProvider.state('start', {
        url: '/start',
        templateUrl: 'templates/start.html',
        controller: 'startCtrl',
        resolve: loginRequired
    })

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/start');
});
```

**EDIT 2**: ngOpenFB Module

```
angular.module('ngOpenFB', [])

    .factory('ngFB', function ($q, $window) {

        function init(params) {
            return $window.openFB.init(params);
        }

        function login(options) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $window.openFB.login(function(result) {
                if (result.status === "connected") {
                    deferred.resolve(result);
                } else {
                    deferred.reject(result);
                }
            }, options);
            return deferred.promise;
        }

        function logout() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $window.openFB.logout(function() {
                deferred.resolve();
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }

        function api(obj) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            obj.success = function(result) {
                deferred.resolve(result);
            };
            obj.error = function(error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            };
            $window.openFB.api(obj);
            return deferred.promise;
        }

        function revokePermissions() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $window.openFB.revokePermissions(
                function() {
                    deferred.resolve();
                },
                function() {
                    deferred.reject();
                }
            );
            return deferred.promise;
        }

        function getLoginStatus() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $window.openFB.getLoginStatus(
                function(result) {
                    deferred.resolve(result);
                }
            );
            return deferred.promise;
        }

        return {
            init: init,
            login: login,
            logout: logout,
            revokePermissions: revokePermissions,
            api: api,
            getLoginStatus: getLoginStatus
        };

    });
```

Comment: Is your ngOpenFB  a provider?

Comment: Sorry, wrong question. Not sure if you are getting some errors in your console. I just was curious about ngFB, if its a provider or not, since you can only inject providers into your config.

Comment: Updated my question with the module

Comment: As I said. you have '.factory('ngFB', function ($q, $window)' and this is not a provider, it is a factory. Which means you won't be able to inject this factory (ngFB) into your config.

Comment: Think i could rewrite the factory as a provider?

Comment: I recommend reading https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Dependency-Injection.  It explains in depth how injectables are created and consumed.

Answer (score 0):

Due to some structure, I'm posting this as an answer.

Configuration blocks in AngularJS do only accept `providers` and the same goes for providers - These do also only accept provides. So the conclusion is, you can only inject a `provider` into a `provider/config`.

You can read more about that [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module), under **Module Loading & Dependencies**.

> A module is a collection of configuration and run blocks which get
>   applied to the application during the bootstrap process. In its
>   simplest form the module consists of a collection of two kinds of
>   blocks:
>
> 1. Configuration blocks - get executed during the provider registrations and configuration phase. Only providers and constants
>      can be injected into configuration blocks. This is to prevent
>      accidental instantiation of services before they have been fully
>      configured.
> 2. Run blocks - get executed after the injector is created and are used to kickstart the application. Only instances and constants can be
>      injected into run blocks. This is to prevent further system
>      configuration during application run time.

Meaning that, you would have to write your own Provider, which you can inject into your config.

The other option is to use the run block of your module. But in your case, this wouldn't be possible, since you are trying to populate your `$stateProvider` with dynamically generated data.